# Can't put buttons on second window using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know why is the window created with nothing when I've put 3 buttons to appear. This is the function where it happens:

```
def Click():
if input_fieldContra.get() == contraseña:
 vent_iniciada = Tk()
 root.withdraw()
 vent_iniciada.geometry("250x200")
 vent_iniciada.mainloop()
 nuevoB = Button(vent_iniciada, text="Nuevo", command=NuevoBot)
 abrirB = Button(vent_iniciada, text="Abrir", command=AbrirBot)
 guardarB = Button(vent_iniciada, text="Guardar", command=GuardarBot)

 nuevoB.grid(vent_iniciada, row=0, column=0)
 abrirB.grid(vent_iniciada, row=2, column=0)
 guardarB.grid(vent_iniciada, row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: Muliple instances of `Tk()` should be avoided.  Change `vent_iniciada` to `Toplevel()` and remove `vent_iniciada.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `.grid()` doesn't take on the parent window. When using grid you should define the parent window inside the widget when widget is created.
`.grid()` options must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, sticky etc.

Secondly, if you move `vent_iniciada.mainloop()` to the bottom of the code, it should work. What happens is that the code is executing:

`vent_iniciada = TK()`

`root.withdraw`

`vent_iniciada.geometry("250x200")`

and this is where you should put your button so the code reads them into the window.

Finally, after gridding the widgets, you tell the program to mainloop everything

`vent_iniciada.mainloop()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to move :

```
vent_iniciada.mainloop()
```

to the last line of the function